# Difference in EPSG:28992 (RD/Amersfoort) definitions

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, proj4js

I need to do some projections between WGS84 (EPSG:4326) and the Dutch RD system (EPSG:28992) in JavaScript.

I use Proj4js for this. When adding the definition from spatialreference.org I noticed a difference with the definition that is embedded in my PostGIS database:

```
// Source: PostGIS SRID 28992 from database
"+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs"

// Source: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/amersfoort-rd-new/proj4js/
"+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"
```

The difference being `+towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725` that is present in the PostGIS definition but not in the spatialreference.org definition.

Is this a meaningful difference? If so, what does this part of the string define?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a meaningful difference, there will be some difference in reprojecting.
Those 7 parameters define a datum shift (translation + rotation + scaling).

If the postgis reprojection is better than the other one, just add those parameters to the Proj4js definition.

You can find additional information on the towgs84 param here https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/GenParms#towgs84-DatumtransformationtoWGS84

Comment: The postgis projection is better, the official EPSG reference is wrong (produces 200 meter shift). Here is a good post about it: https://oegeo.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/note-to-self-the-one-and-only-rd-projection-string/

Comment: @tilt EPSG only started publishing WKT strings with v2 last year. EPSG is also "late-binding." Transformation information is not linked to a CRS definition but chosen when needed.

Comment: That is interesting information @mkennedy, thanks. Do you happen to have a link for more info on that?

Comment: Also thanks @tilt, that is exactly what I did (used the projection from PostGIS in Proj4js by adding it).

Comment: [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org) and the [main website](http://www.epsg.org) (look for guidance notes). Note: I help maintain it.

Comment: Any idea why it hasn't been changed, for example [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/amersfoort-rd-new/)? I also don't understand how proj4Java seems to convert the coordinates correctly with the shorter definition, while proj4js seems to use the same definition and outputs wrong coordinates?